# Python doesn't see files in modules

Tags: python, module

So I split my code into different files that are in the project directory
[image: files in directory]

But when I import those modules into main.py it complains that it can't see files in them

```
import pygame
import winsound
import random
import math
#import wGeneration
import rGeneration
from Camera import camera
from KeyHandle import KeyHandle
```

On importing Keyhandle it gives out this error

[image: keyhandle]

This is what is in the KeyHandle module though

```
import main
import pygame

def KeyHandle():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                main.dire.append(3)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                main.dire.append(2)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.KEYUP:
                main.dire.remove(3)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                main.dire.remove(2)
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any circular imports in any of your modules

Comment: what does that mean? so if I'm in KeyHandle module I can't import files from main.py if I'm importing Keyhandle in main.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using circular imports. [There are tons of explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+circular+import) on what it is, but you are importing the same module across multiple modules. One solution is to import the modules in the scope of the functions, instead of globally in the file, ie:

```
def KeyHandle():
    import main # Import here instead
    import pygame
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                main.dire.append(3)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                main.dire.append(2)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.KEYUP:
                main.dire.remove(3)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                main.dire.remove(2)
```